# Create a data pipeline with nested JSON files on S3 for QuickSight

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I’d like to create some tables on AWS Athena using the data from JSON files located on S3 for QuickSight The json files are generated everyday following the folder path rule like YYYY/MM/DD.

I checked AWS documentation and tried some tutorials. It doesn’t seem difficult if the json data isn’t nested but my case they are nested.

I’d like to know the best practice of how to flatten the JSON data using AWS solutions such as Athena and Glue and stored the data into tables. My goal is to show the data on QuickSight so I thought Athena is a way to go.

I already created table schemas. Is there any good practice for such a pipeline?

Comment: check this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-and-visualize-nested-json-data-with-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight/ . You can also leverage partitioning but the folder structure is not in key value format either you can use Glue crawler to populate partitions or use alter table add partitions and give location